# Playing a Sound Effect (mp3)

Tags: java, mp3, media-player, jmf, javasound

Does anyone know how to play an mp3 file in Java? I have a little sound effect that I want to play. Here's what I have

```
import java.io.*;
import java.media.*;

File mp3Correct;
Player correct;

/* Load mp3 files */
mp3Correct = new File ("C:\\correct.mp3");

/* Create media players */
correct = Manager.createPlayer( mp3Correct.toURI() );  //<--error

/* Play the sound effect */
correct.start();
```

This is the error message:

> no suitable method found for createPlayer(URI)
>
> ```
> method Manager.createPlayer(DataSource) is not applicable
>   (actual argument URI cannot be converted to DataSource by method invocation conversion)
> method Manager.createPlayer(MediaLocator) is not applicable
>   (actual argument URI cannot be converted to MediaLocator by method invocation conversion)
> method Manager.createPlayer(URL) is not applicable
>   (actual argument URI cannot be converted to URL by method invocation conversion)
> ```

According to the Java documentation,

> The simplest way to create a Player is from a locator in the URI syntax. Given a locator, createPlayer will create a Player suitable to handle the media identified by the locator.

But I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?  Thank you!

Comment: Note that most of JMF is not required for this task.  The only part that is necessary is the [mp3plugin.jar](http://pscode.org/lib/mp3plugin.jar).  It contains an SPI for decoding MP3.  The SPI means that all you need to do is add it to the run-time class-path of the app. to add support for decoding Mp3 using Java Sound.

Answer (score 1):

i'd imagine you want `toURL()`.